# Sort images according to their similarity (assuming function to find out any 2 images' difference is given)

Tags: algorithms

Say I have 10 images,
and a function `getDiff(image1, image2)` to get the difference (int value) between any 2 images.
[image]

What will be the best way to sort the images so that we have similar ones sorted together?

A brutal force method would be to pick 1 image and then do `getDiff` to all other 9 images to find the most similar one. Then you do `getDiff` to the rest 8 images to get next one.. with time comlexity being n! (n is the total number of images)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not belongs to **Mathematics**...

Comment: you probably cannot sort, but perhaps you could cluster them.

Comment: "Sort" implies a total ordering, something one-dimensional. But images can be modified in many different ways, and clearly cannot be organized into one dimension. Perhaps some kind of tree structure could be used to organize them, but a sorted ordering? No.